# excel, vba or regex to copy values downwards based on repeated values

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have the following records:

```
62      
STARTHERE   1.1 vol. 84 no. 1 1996  01.1 A 0 1 1996 04 24 0
STARTHERE   1.2 vol. 84 no. 2 1996  01.2 A 0 1 1996 05 23 0
STARTHERE   1.3 vol. 84 no. 3 1996  01.3 A 1 1 1996 08 13 0
STARTHERE   1.4 vol. 84 no. 4 1996  01.4 A 0 1 1996 10 15 0
STARTHERE   1.5 vol. 84 no. 5 1996  01.5 A 0 1 1997 01 22 0
STARTHERE   1.6 vol. 84 no. 6 1996  01.6 A 0 1 1997 02 10 0
63      
STARTHERE   1.1 95:1 Feb 2002   1.1 A 0 1 2002 06 03 0
STARTHERE   1.2 95:2 Apr 2002   1.2 A 0 1 2002 06 17 0
STARTHERE   1.3 95:3 Jun 2002   1.3 A 0 1 2002 07 18 0
STARTHERE   1.4 95:4 Aug 2002   1.4 A 0 1 2003 02 24 0
STARTHERE   1.5 95:5 Oct 2002   1.5 A 0 1 2003 02 24 0
64
65
STARTHERE   1.1 34:1 Mar 1996   1.1 A 0 1 1996 07 16 0
STARTHERE   1.2 34:2 Jun 1996   1.2 A 0 1 1996 09 19 0
STARTHERE   1.3 34:3 Sep 1996   1.3 A 0 1 1996 12 17 0
```

I don't know if this is possible in excel, vba in excel or even through regex. I want to fill the lowest numerical value (e.g. 62) and replace the lower rows with values "STARTHERE" up until the next numerical value (63). Right now, it's done manually but I was thinking if there is a way of doing this mechanically. Through excel formula, VBA, or regex, as these are what I'm familiar with. So that I can get below, it's okay also that the 62 with blank value to the right are stripped but I'm fine even if it's not:

```
62  
62  1.1 vol. 84 no. 1 1996  01.1 A 0 1 1996 04 24 0
62  1.2 vol. 84 no. 2 1996  01.2 A 0 1 1996 05 23 0
62  1.3 vol. 84 no. 3 1996  01.3 A 1 1 1996 08 13 0
62  1.4 vol. 84 no. 4 1996  01.4 A 0 1 1996 10 15 0
62  1.5 vol. 84 no. 5 1996  01.5 A 0 1 1997 01 22 0
62  1.6 vol. 84 no. 6 1996  01.6 A 0 1 1997 02 10 0
62
62  1.1 95:1 Feb 2002   1.1 A 0 1 2002 06 03 0
63  1.2 95:2 Apr 2002   1.2 A 0 1 2002 06 17 0
63  1.3 95:3 Jun 2002   1.3 A 0 1 2002 07 18 0
63  1.4 95:4 Aug 2002   1.4 A 0 1 2003 02 24 0
63  1.5 95:5 Oct 2002   1.5 A 0 1 2003 02 24 0
64
65
65  1.1 34:1 Mar 1996   1.1 A 0 1 1996 07 16 0
65  1.2 34:2 Jun 1996   1.2 A 0 1 1996 09 19 0
65  1.3 34:3 Sep 1996   1.3 A 0 1 1996 12 17 0
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You can do this with VBA. Research these VBA topics: Cell References, If, and Loops. It's also possible with cell formulas. I think the VBA approach is cleaner and definitely easier to re-run in the future (it sounds like you need to do this on a regular basis).

Comment: It's definitely possible with VBA. Start with the cells in range A1:AXXX. Copy the first value that is a number. Fill in the subsequent cells until a number is found. Two loops shoud be able to accomplish it.

Comment: Hi! Yeah a number with blank values to the right starts all the sequences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this data is from an Excel spreadsheet, with both the numerical values and the value "STARTHERE" are on the first column (column A). The other data are on column B, C, etc.

Basically, I will loop through the first column from the top to the bottom row. If the value within the selector cell is not a number, it will be equal to the one right above it. If it is, then we skip to the next cell.

```
  Sub help()
        ActiveSheet.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "0"
        For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
            If Not Information.IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1)) Then Cells(i, 1).value = Cells(i - 1, 1).value
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! I tried the script but I got the following: "Application defined or object-defined error." Trying to debug it but I only know how to put the macro. TIA!

Comment: Give me your data/a subset of your data in whatever format you have, and I may be able to help.

Comment: Hi! here is the file: http://128.199.159.143/serials_forregex_20150805_1052_fin_.xlsx

Comment: schnydszch: You can fix this by starting the loop from row number 2 (replace "for i = 1" with "for i =2"). The problem is there is no row number 0, so when you the loop start with row number 1, it will look at low number 0 for reference, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot on this. Already finished with the project. But this code be helpful in the future. Cheers! :)